# How to synchronize/inherit/bind transformations between a parent graphics item and n-number of "children" items in a scene? (PyQt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am currently trying to write a simple test program in PyQt5 where I can "attach" children graphicsitems to a parent graphicsitem that I can use to control the children. In other words, how can I make the children move and transform alongside the parent item?

What I've tried so far looks something like this....

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMenu, QAction, qApp, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import QHBoxLayout, QSplitter, QPixmap, QSplashScreen,\
QGraphicsScene, QTextEdit, QFrame, QSize, QGraphicsRectItem, QBrush,  QImage,\
QGraphicsPixmapItem, QGraphicsItem, QPainterPath, QColor, QGraphicsView
from PyQt5 import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class Mainwindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setCentralWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget())

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.rect = Rect()
        self.subrect = Subrect()
        self.subrect.setPos(self.rect.scenePos())
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.scene.addItem(self.rect)
        self.scene.addItem(self.subrect)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(-500, -250, 1000, 500)
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene, self)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 1000, 500)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

class Rect(QGraphicsRectItem):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setRect(100, 100, 100, 100)
        self.setBrush(QColor(54, 69, 200))
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsScenePositionChanges)


class Subrect(Rect):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setRect(150, 150, 30, 30)
        self.setBrush(QColor(0, 255, 255))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)}")

    mainw = Mainwindow()

    ex = Mainwindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As you can probably see, here I've tried two different approaches. One being getting the parent's position by inheritance through classes, the other being using the .setPos(self.rect.scenePos())

I am a yet a bit inexperienced at programming. That's why it might not look too appealing. Please let me know if additional information is needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of features do you want to synchronize?

Comment: What do you mean by to synchronize / inherit / bind transformations?

Comment: Basically I would like to make composite graphicsitems so that a child item is literally "attached" to the parent graphicsitem. For example, A big (parent) rectitem and a smaller (child) graphicsitem. The intention is to be able to attach the smaller one to the bigger one (parent) so that the child moves with the parent. So far I only need this for moving and rotation.

Comment: A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46830549/pyqt-how-to-parent-positions-of-qgraphicsitem

Comment: the move is simple, but the turn is a bit confusing, for example if the parent item rotates on itself the child object must rotate with respect to the parent or should it only rotate with respect to itself? And another question is how do you want to rotate it? I mean, it's going to click, or use a menu.

Comment: Actually, I have already implemented a working rotation feature on the parent itself that uses keys A and D to respectively rotate 45 degrees CCW or CW on each press step. About the rotation, I am trying to implement something that syncs rotation to the children relative to the parent's origin or axis.

Although it isn't visible in my post, I have implemented the rotation method for graphicsitems in a bigger project...

Comment: What is the origin or axis of the parent? the top-left, top-right, ..., center? 
You have to be precise.

Comment: Center, preferably. I've got that covered for the parent item with setOffset() method already.

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary that you do something new, the reference system of the children items is with respect to the parent so if the father moves the son will do it too, and if he rotates he will do it too.

But for this you must pass a parent that is different from the inheritance. for this you must use `setParent()` or pass it as argued in the constructor:

```
some_children = Some_Type_Item(some_parent)
```

To show this I created the following example:

```
import sys
import math

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Rect(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setRect(-50, -50, 100, 100)
        self.setBrush(QColor(54, 69, 200))
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsScenePositionChanges)

class Subrect(Rect):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setRect(-15, -15, 30, 30)
        self.setBrush(QColor(0, 255, 255))


class Scene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QGraphicsScene.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setSceneRect(-500, -250, 1000, 500)

        self.item_parent = Rect()
        self.addItem(self.item_parent)
        for i in range(10):
            item_children = Subrect(self.item_parent)
            angle = i*math.pi/5
            pos = i*20.0*math.cos(angle), 100.0*math.sin(angle)
            item_children.setPos(*pos)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        angle = self.item_parent.rotation()
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_A:
            angle += 45
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_D:
            angle -= 45
        self.item_parent.setRotation(angle)


class Mainwindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget())
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.scene = Scene(self)
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene, self)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Mainwindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```